# RoR: Can you send an email with an inline form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email, survey

Im using ROR to create this application.

So I've been asked by a client to create a survey for my web application. They want this survey to be emailed out to users under specific circumstances. Is it possible to have the survey actually inside of the email? so that the user can go ahead and fill out the fields in the email instead of sending a link and having the user redirect to the survey page on the website?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Forms can be embedded in emails, however the individual email client determines how it is handled and displayed. According to [this blog](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2435/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/):

"Given the sporadic support for forms in emails, we recommend linking to a form on a website in an email rather than embedding it therein. This is the safest, most reliable solution to pairing an email message with a form. More people will see it and be able to use it, and as a result participation will increase."

Hope this helps!